Identifying this Brother toner chip
This is the chip on my Brother toner TN760 cartridge. A search for the numbers didn't give me any results. Any idea who makes this? I am looking for the datasheet of the microchip in the middle.
Brother TN760 chip showing microcontroller parts:


Looks like a small flash memory. There are a number of websites claiming you can reset the toner counter, perhaps you can snoop the communication and learn something about the part? https://premiumtoners.com/blogs/news/how-to-reset-brother-tn760-toner-counter

Based on observations from other cartridges, and the million-pieces market they are in:
That will be an ASIC (application-specific IC; solely made for this purpose) without public datasheet, or a generic cheap 8 bit microcontroller with a hard burned in firmware (either as mask ROM or in EEPROM memory with the programming fuse burned).
There's nothing you could buy to replicate that functionality; all that you can learn about its behaviour would have to be observed externally (i.e., sniffing communication and pin states while built into a printer).

@Colin that is probably the programming chain used in the factory when a couple dozen to hundred of these boards are still attached to a larger panel, before they get sawed into individual PCBs. I don't see your seven-segment thing at all – or do you mean the manufacturing date? YY-WW means "interpret the 21 as year and the 24 as week of the year; that's when this was built".

You will not be able to buy that part (except by taking it out of a Brother toner cartridge). That's kind of the point of it.
Many such chips have been cloned and are used to make compatible cartridges, and some are available as little PCB modules as you show (eg.  TN289 where there are different chips for C, M, Y, K). I don't see the particular one you have though.

And even if you could buy it, it may contain custom contents which needs to be uploaded by the factory. An empty flash memory etc IC won't do anyone any good in this context.
